# How can I filter lines from file and write them to another one?

Tags: groovy

I have a large log file which needs to be read and condensed to only vital information.
So far, I don't have much, but this is it:

```
String fileContents = new File('C:/Users/jake.oneill/'logname'').text
```

fileContents.eachline

Is there a contains command I could use? I can hardly read the file in groovy, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
new File('C:/Users/jake.oneill/logname').eachLine { line ->
    // impose whatever you want to check here
    if(line.startsWith('IMPORTANT')) {
        // do whatever you want to do with the line here            
        println line
    }
}
```

Does that help?